# Why does my Path.expanduser keep getting this following error message? ['str' object has no attribute '_drv']

Tags: python

I am trying to use Path.expanduser() to extract the base directory of all of my web app users. I intend to use the base directory to locate the Downloads folder and direct all of my web app exports into their respective Downloads folder. But when I implement this function and try to test it out by checking directory it returns me, I only get the error message of ['str' object has no attribute '_drv'] instead of the base directory.

Imported pathlib into my app.py

snippet of my app.py

```
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session, abort, jsonify, url_for, Markup
from wtforms import Form, TextField, TextAreaField, validators, StringField, SubmitField, SelectField, SelectMultipleField
from werkzeug import secure_filename
from pprint import pprint
from pathlib import Path 

@app.route('/process_pt', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def process_pt():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        colSelection = request.form.get('selectedCol')
        cols = colSelection.split(",")
        valSelection = request.form.get('selectedVal')
        global filtered_df
        filtered_df = pd.pivot_table(filtered_df, values=[valSelection], index=cols, aggfunc=np.sum)
        filtered_df.reset_index()

        dl_path = Path.expanduser('~\\Users')
        print(str(dl_path))

        return render_template(
            'summarized_df.html',
            data = filtered_df.to_html()
        )
```

Expected: dl_path to return the base directory
Actual: Error Message 'str' object has no attribute '_drv'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using `os.path.expanduser` for working with strings.

`pathlib.Path.expanduser` is a method of `pathlib.Path` objects. You could convert your string to such an object and do what you want with `Path('~\\Users').expanduser()`.